# Maximal determinant of $4n \times 4n$ matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Find the maximal determinant of a $4n \times 4n$ matrix with $2n$ entries equal to $1$ and $2n$ entries equal to $-1$.

---

My attempt:

For $n=1$, we take the following matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 
     0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 2
 \end{pmatrix}

But, instead of $2$ I would put any other value, so does this determinant diverge?

Comment: Perhaps they meant "all the other entries must be zero".

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  A book? Lecture notes?

Comment: What does the arrangement needs to satisfy in order for the determinant to be nonzero?